# Is there any difference between _cq_dialog.xml _cq_dialog/.content.xml?

Tags: aem, aem-6, aem-touch-ui

In most AEM components I've seen there is a file _cq_dialog.xml that defines a Touch UI dialog to configure the component. However, when I export a component with a CRX DE package, it contains _cq_dialog as a directory with .content.xml inside.

Is there any difference whether the dialog is defined in _cq_dialog.xml or _cq_dialog/.content.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no difference between the two. Both are valid serializations of a `cq:dialog` node.
However, the version with the folder has the added benefit of allowing you to put descendant nodes of `cq:dialog` into separate files.